# Avoid looping through map if single item change

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a List component as shown bellow. Component renders list of Items and listens for item changes using websocket (updateItems function). Everything works fine except that I noticed that when a single item change my renderItems function loops through all of items.

Sometimes I have more than 150 items with 30 updates in a second. When this happens my application noticeable slows down (150x30=4500 loops) and when another updateItems happens after, its still processing first updateItems. I implemented shouldComponentUpdate in Items component where I compare nextProps.item with this.props.item to avoid unnecessary render calls for items that are not changed. Render function is not called but looks like that just call to items.map((item, index) slowing down everything.

My question is, is there a way to avoid looping through all items and change only the one that updated?

Note that other object data are not changed in this case, only items array within object.

```
class List extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            object: null, // containing items array with some other data 
                          // such as objectId, ...
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // call to server to retrieve object (response)
        this.setState({object: response})
    }
    
    renderItems= (items) => {
        return items.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <Item key={item.id} item={item}/>
            );
        });
    }

    // this is called as a websocket onmessage callback
    // data contains change item that should be replaced in items array
    updateItems = data => {
        // cloning object here in order to avoid mutation of its state
        // the object does not contains functions and null values and cloning
        // this way works in my case
        let cloneObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.object));
        
        let index = // call to a function to get index needed
        cloneObject.items[index] = data.change;
        this.setState({object: cloneObject});
    }

    render() {
        return (
           this.state.object && {this.renderItems(this.state.object.items)}
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: you could check out the `shouldComponentUpdate` lifecycle

Answer (score 1):

First I would verify that your Item components are not re-rendering with a console.log(). I realize you have written that they don't in your description but I'm unconvinced the map loop is the total cause of the issue. It would be great if you posted your Component code because I'm curious if your render method is expensive for some reason as well.

The method you are currently using to clone your last state is a deep clone, it's not only slow but it will also cause each shallow prop compare to resolve true every time. (ie: lastProps !== newProps will always resolve true when using JSON.parse/stringify method)

To keep each item's data instance you can do something like this in your state update:

```
const index = state.items.findIndex(item => item._id === newItem._id);
const items = [
  ...state.items.slice(0, index),
  newItem,
  ...state.items.slice(index + 1),
];
```

Doing this keeps all the other items intact, except for the one being updated.

Finally as per your question how to prevent this list re-rendering, this is possible.
I would do this by using moving the data storage out of state and into two redux reducers. Use one array reducer to track the _id of each item and an object reducer to track the actual item data.

Array structure:

```
['itemID', 'itemID'...]
```

Object structure:

```
{
  [itemID]: {itemData},
  [itemID]: {itemData},
  ...
}
```

Use the _id array to render the items, this will only re-render when the array of _ids is changed.

```
class List() {
...
  render() {
    return this.props.itemIds.map(_id => <Item id={_id} />);
  }
}
```

Then use another container or better yet `useSelector` to have each item fetch its data from the state and re-render when it's data is changed.

```
function Item(props) {
  const {id} = props;
  const data = useSelector(state => state.items[id]);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will try with it. How do I update Item from the List component? Also using selector and updating selected one?

Comment: Since the data would then be stored in the redux state you would dispatch actions to modify it from either component. Take a look at: https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch and https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping the child component with React.memo(). I had a similar problem with a huge form (over 50 controlled inputs). Every time I would've typed in an input all the form would've get re-rendered.

```
const Item = memo(
  ({ handleChange, value }) => {
    return (
      <>
        <input name={el} onChange={handleChange} defaultValue={value} />
      </>
    );
  },
  (prevProps, nextProps) => {
    return nextProps.values === prevProps.values;
  }
```

Also, if you're passing through props a handler function as I did above, it's worth mentioning that you should wrap it inside a useCallback() hook to prevent recreation if the arguments to the function did not changed. Something like this:

```
const handleChange = useCallback(e => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  setValues(prevProps => {
    const newProps = { ...prevProps, [name]: value };
    return newProps;
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: I can try with that. But as I mentioned in the question, implementing shouldComponentUpdate in Item component actually prevented render call in Item component. But in the next step, I removed <Item> instantiation from renderItems function and did console.log to test it, and with only console.log I noticed slowdowns - 4500 console.logs in a second. I would like to prevent loop through all items if possible.

Comment: I'll share a sandbox where I explained for my colleagues the different approaches for dealing with rerendering. Maybe it helps you somehow: https://codesandbox.io/s/re-rendering-optimization-7b1po

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario I would recommend don't use state for your array rather create state for every individual element and update that accordingly. Something like this

```
class List extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            individualObject: {}
        };
    }
        
    object = response; // your data

    renderItems= (items) => {
            this.setState({
            individualObject: {...this.state.individualObject, ...{[item.id]: item}
        })

        return items.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <Item key={item.id} item={item}/>
            );
        });
    }

    updateItems = data => {
        let cloneObject = {...this.object}
        
        let index = // call to a function to get index needed
        cloneObject.items[index] = data.change;
                this.setState({
            individualObject: {...this.state.individualObject, ...{[item.index]: item}
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
           this.renderItems(this.object)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, except my renderItems function look like this: return Object.keys(items).map((key, index) => { 
            return (
                <Item key={items[key].id} item={items[key]}/>
            );
        });
but the result is the same. map function is called for each item I have in the individualObject even I just update single one: this.setState({individualObject: {...this.state.individualObject, ...{[data.change.itemId]: data.change}}});

Comment: This calls setState in the render method and will cause an infiniute loop. The parent will still loop through all the children to render everytime a child is updated.